# Quick add previous in sublime text 2

Tags: sublimetext2

Is there a quick add previous in sublime text 2 like the quick add next(ctrl+d)?

Relevant lines in keymap

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+d"], "command": "find_under_expand" },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+k", "ctrl+d"], "command": "find_under_expand_skip" },
```

I tried changing that `find_under_expand` to `find_over_expand` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F3</kbd> to move the selection to the previous occurrence, and once you've reached the start of where you want to make multiple selections you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>, but to my knowledge there is no way to make multiple selections in reverse without writing a specialized plugin.